# How does IFTTT know when an external event has happened?

Tags: github, if-this-then-that

I want to put together a simple tool to sync some documents with GitHub issues. I can do this using APIs on a timer say hourly.

I notice IFTTT has GitHub support like "when a new issue is raised..." and I have no idea how they do this. They don't seem to let you see any of the code so I'm not sure if they use the regular GitHub API, or integrators provide special IFTTT interfaces.

Comment: We can only assume, but we won't have a definitive answer. Probably GitHub's team did the integration with IFTTT, and so the code is private. Maybe GitHub has some web hooks that support this? In addition, I don't think the question belongs here in WebApps

Comment: Why not? Ifttt is a web app and there is a tag for it

Comment: @Mr.Boy, Did Ifttt ask for your github auth or does it work for any 3rdparty repo?